# Thermal Conductivity Conversion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-conductivity, unit-conversion

I need to convert a thermal conduction unit `W/m.K` to `Btu/ft.h.°F`. 
I have `400 W/m.K` and I need to find this value in `Btu/ft.h.°F`. I know that `1W=3.41214 Btu/h`, `1m=3.2808ft` and `1K=-457,87°F`.I replaced all the values in the equation and got to `-0.9085 Btu/ft.h.°F`. But these values are incorrect according to internet queries and also in the book, could someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kelvin is a unit of temperature change (interval) in the thermal conductivity equation.

So you need to find what a temperature change in degree fahrenheit corresponds to a temperature change of one kelvin.

Comment: I understood, so for 1 unit change in K I have 1.8 unit changes in F. Thank you.

Comment: @EduardoCardoso You can always check your conversion by using one of the many online unit converters.